# Linux mount Windows samba share for all users

Tags: permissions, mount, samba

I'm mounting a Windows Samba share on my Linux machine (SUSE 11) using the following.

```
mount -t cifs -o username=myname,password=12345 //10.10.0.78/smb /share/smb
```

It works fine except it has the following permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 10 19:35 smb
```

If I try to change the permissions with

```
sudo chmod 777 /share/smb
```

I get permission denied even as root. How can I get around this so that non root users can access the share?

*NOTE*

On the Windows side the share has full access to all users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to set the permissions during the mount not after

```
mount -t cifs -o username=myname,password=12345,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 //10.10.0.78/smb /share/smb
```